# String split in c without changing original

Tags: c, split

we have an school asignment to make a specific function of string split 
the header and arguments of function is given cannot change them .
this function should split original by delimiter into array of string that store each part of string delimiter not included and in additon for each delimiter increase size

```
void stringSplit(const char *original, char result[50][256], int* size, char delim){
    size_t begin = 0;
    if(!original){
        return;
    }
    for(size_t i=0; i<strlen(original);i++ ){
        if (original[i] == delim){
            int str_begin = 0;
            for( ; begin < i; begin++ ){
                result[*size][str_begin] = original[begin];
                str_begin++;
            }
            (*size)++;
            begin ++ ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool. Do you have a question about it?

Comment: `for(size_t i=0; i<strlen(original);i++ )` -> `for (size_t i = 0;  original[i] != '\0'; i++ )`, because `strlen()` **counts** the characters and that is inefficient.

Comment: `we have an school asignment` - Do not get me involved in your assignments.

Comment: @EdHeal - its fair to get involved in assignments if the questioner has make effort to do the work but is stuck. The ones I object to is when the assignment text simply gets pasted as the question.

Comment: "we" implies ownership. "please help me with..." would be better

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Since `original` isn't modified in the loop, I would expect the optimizer to pre-compute the string length and replace the `for` loop condition with that value, rather than calling `strlen` each time through, no? Probably still not as efficient as what you've proposed, but I wouldn't expect much of a performance hit from using `strlen`. Just wondering outloud, I haven't looked at any assembly.

Comment: The strings must be `'\0'`-terminated. Before `(*size)++;` do: `result[*size][str_begin] = 0;`

Comment: What is the actual problem you are facing / what is not working? And  what  is your debugger telling you?

Comment: Make a copy of `original`, and then use `strtok()` and `strcpy()`.

Comment: ... or use `strchr`, `memcpy` and terminate your destination  strings.

Comment: if you are having trouble, learn to use your debugger to step through the code.

Comment: @yano correct. As I recall correctly, `strlen`, just uses a cast to `unsigned` to check 4-chars per-iteration instead of 1. You won't see much measurable difference until you work with strings of many hundreds (or thousands) of characters. (I did the tests -- because retentive minds just have to know....)

Comment: @yano, Suppose that it's true. The optimizer did find out that the stirng didn't changed and replaced the call with the fixed length. It still looks like PHP and just for that it deserves to be changed. And also, the `original[i] != '\0'` is more idiomatic.

Comment: @pm100 tried that even my teacher couldnt tell what doesnt work i suppose it was something with pointer i do not understand them well yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is OK, but you have a couple of errors:

Your string copies are not `'\0'`-terminated. Also you are not taking into
account when multiple delimiters follow in a row.

If you are not allowed to use
functions like `strchr` and `strncpy`, then you can do this:

```
size_t str_begin = 0;
*size = 0; // the user may have passed an uninitialized int variable

for(size_t i = 0; original[i] && *size < 50; ++i)
{
    if(original[i] == delim)
    {
        size_t sublen = i - str_begin;
        if(sublen == 0)
        {
            // skip delimiter, last character was also a
            // delimiter and/or the first character in
            // original is a delimiter
            str_begin++;
            continue;

            // or if you want to have empty words instead of skipping
            // results[*size] = 0;
            // (*size)++;
        }

        if(sublen > 256)
            sublen = 256;

        for(size_t j = 0; j < sublen; ++j)
            result[*size][j] = original + str_begin + j;

        result[*size][j] = 0; // \0-terminating string

        (*size)++;
        str_begin = i + 1; // updating str_begin to next char
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The straight forward way of doing so is - as suggested by Barmar - to make a copy of the original string and then work with `strtok()` and `strcpy`.

Alternatively, you could use  `strchr` in a loop to find the delimiters and `memcpy` to copy the memory between the previous delimiter and the next one. See  the following code, which also takes the boundaries of the result array into account:

```
void stringSplit(const char *original, char result[50][256], int *size, char
                 delim)
{
    if(!original){
        return ;
    }

    *size = 0;
    const char* nextDelim;
    const char* prevDelim = original;
    do  {
        nextDelim = strchr(prevDelim,delim);
        size_t len = nextDelim ? (nextDelim - prevDelim) : strlen(prevDelim);
        if (len >= 256) {
            len = 256-1;
        }
        memcpy(result[*size],prevDelim,len);
        result[*size][len] = '\0';
        (*size)++;
        prevDelim = nextDelim ? nextDelim+1 : NULL;
    }
    while(nextDelim && *size < 50);
}

int main() {

    char result[50][256];
    int  size;
    stringSplit("Hello, this, is", result, &size, ',');

    return 0;

}
```

Hope it helps.